# open view in new tab with ajax parameter c# mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

Please help I've tried everything I could, I want to open new view with parameter but in a new tab, and my view url is same as the ajax url I have. I am so confused, still new to this.

this is my javascript code:

```
 $(document).on('click', "a.clsApproval", function (e) {
        debugger;            
        var vData = JSON.parse($(this).attr('dataTake'));
        var vCode = vData.MUIGCode;
        var vID = vData.Id;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/ApprovalMapPerUserEpr/Index',
            data: { Id: vID, MUIGCode: vCode },
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (mdl)
            {
                debugger;
                var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "ApprovalMapPerUserEpr")';
                window.open(url);

            },
            error: function (mdl)
            {
                debugger;
            }
        });    
    });
```

this is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int Id, string MUIGCode)
    {
        if (Session["role_id"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            var cnn = new SqlConnection(SQLCon);
            var cmmd = new SqlCommand();
            var query = "";

            try
            {
                query = "SELECT[dbo].[M_UIGH].[MUIGCode] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGH].[CreateDate] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGH].[CompanyID] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGH].[CompanyName] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGH].[BranchID] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGH].[BranchName] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGH].[UserID] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGH].[UserName] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGH].[UserDept] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGD].[Id] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGD].[CostCenter] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGD].[CCName] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGD].[CCLevel] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGD].[ItemGroupCod] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGD].[ItemGroupName] \n " +
                            ",[dbo].[M_UIGD].[CoaItemGroup] \n " +
                        "FROM [dbo].[M_UIGD] \n " +
                        "INNER JOIN [dbo].[M_UIGH] ON [dbo].[M_UIGH].[MUIGCode] = [dbo].[M_UIGD].[MUIGCode] \n " +
                        "WHERE [dbo].[M_UIGD].[MUIGCode] = '" + MUIGCode + "' " +
                            "AND [dbo].[M_UIGD].[Id] =  '" + Id + "' ";

                cnn.Open();
                cmmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
                SqlDataReader dreader = cmmd.ExecuteReader();
                MapingUIGD map = new MapingUIGD();

                if (dreader.Read())
                {
                    map.MUIGCode = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("MUIGCode"));
                    map.Id = dreader.GetInt32(dreader.GetOrdinal("Id"));
                    map.CompanyID = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("CompanyID"));
                    map.CompanyName = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("CompanyName"));
                    map.BranchID = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("BranchID"));
                    map.BranchName = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("BranchName"));
                    map.UserID = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("UserID")); 
                    map.UserName = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("UserName")); 
                    map.UserDept = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("UserDept")); 
                    map.costCenter = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("CostCenter")); 
                    map.costName = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("CCName")); 
                    map.costLevel = Convert.ToInt32(dreader["CCLevel"]);
                    map.itemGroupCode = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("ItemGroupCod")); 
                    map.itemGroupName = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("ItemGroupName")); 
                    map.coa = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("CoaItemGroup")); 
                }

                dreader.Close();
                cnn.Close();
                ViewBag.Title = "Approval Mapping Per User (ePR)";
                return View(map);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wPkS.png) is my form, the one which should open new tab is link approval setting, it should open the approval view in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an ajax call you can use `Html.ActionLink` like this:

`@Html.ActionLink("linkText", "Action", new {controller="Controller"}, new {target="_blank"})`

This will call your controller action directly and open the result in a new tab.

Comment: i'm sorry, i've tried that one. my problem is that url on success function ajax is same with url ajax.

Comment: how about the parameters that i give in ajax data? i used ajax because i have to send 2 parameters, id and code.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use the answer that @jpishko suggested you would need to add the parameters like this

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText: "Click Me",
    actionName: "Index",
    controllerName: "ApprovalMapPerUserEpr",
    routeValues: new {
        Id = "3",
        MUIGCode = "test"
    },
    htmlAttributes: new
    {
        target = "_blank"
    })
```

Or you could add a form to your html to look something like this

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Index", "ApprovalMapPerUserEpr")" target="_blank">
    <input name="Id" value="3"/>
    <input name="MUIGCode" value="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="Click Me" />
</form>
```

and then have the values for Id and MUIGCode be whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

To open a view in a new tab , you could use html attribute target ="_blank"
Either use this in html or add in @Html.ActionLink .